# Is it possible to make Office 365 on mac textbox navigation keys consistent with macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office

I have to use MS office 365 (ex: Outlook 16.55) tools for mac. MS being MS, they have different text navigation shortcuts on mac. Is it possible to make them the same as rest of the macOS? Particularly:

```
Control D & H    Delete / Backspace
Control A & E     ⇇ ⇉
Control F & B     ←→
Control P & N    ↑↓
```

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

Scandinavian keyboard layout is really bad for development work and unix shells, because back in the days only US layout existed.

People solve this by remapping keys using Karabiner-Elements (https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).

Karabiner can perform all the keyboard remaps you desire.
It is stable, free, and open source. The developers accept donations. I am not affiliated with the project in any way other than as a happy user. I have used it for many years over many macOS iterations. Primarily to remap Caps Lock to create a "Hyper key".

As a starting point, look at the community submitted complex keyboard remaps by searching for "Office": (https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=office), for example the "Use left control key as command key in Microsoft Office (rev 1)" remap.

This shows how to create a complex modification only within one (or more) particular application, and not system-wide.

`Goku` is a separate tool for configuring Karabiner (https://github.com/yqrashawn/GokuRakuJoudo). Learning it will pay off in the long run.

Another tool which is easier to use and might work, is `BetterTouchTool`.

The reason I will suggest trying Karabiner first, is because the particular remaps you mention will probably need a change "deeper down" than what BTT can do for you *reliably*. Also it is non-free and closed source. Other than that, BTT is also very useful for customizing both Office and elsewhere.